# Improve split large table algorithm in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a very large table ~1TB of history data in MySQL 5.6. I want to split the data into many smaller tables per sites. My current idea is to iterate in chunks of 10'000 records and inside this loop iterate through each chunk to all sites. This has taken more than 2 days (stopped).

Is there any way of improving this query?

#### Code

```
for min_id,max_id in range(1,max_id_in_table,chunk_size):
    for site_id in [site_id_1,site_id_2,site_id_3]:
        insert into history_table_<site_id> (field_a,field_b,field_c)
        select field_a,field_b,field_c
        from history_table h  where h.site_id = <site_id> AND h.id > <min_id> AND h.id <= <max_id> ;
```

Comment: *i want to split it to many smaller tables per sites* Maybe partitioning by `site` value is enough?

Comment: not sure i am fully understand what do you mean by partitioning

Comment: [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual  /  Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html).

Comment: i am using azure Azure Database for MySQL servers  and one of the bottleneck is the copy DB of Azure to snapshot so i think that even when partitioning the table entire needs to be copied so i am not sure that it will solve my issue

Comment: what happens when again the size increases? Partition is what needed splitting will take huge time but partition does that for you(internally based on partition key). To know more refer [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) credit @rickjames

Comment: Before embarking on this lengthy task, please explain what you hope to gain by the result.  Performance?  Not likely.  (Let's see a query that you think will be faster.)  Space?  Won't happen.  Maintenance nightmare?  Yes.